# "En lugar de retornar una cadena (str), el resultado obtenido fue de tipo 'tuple'" cómo hago que sea str?

Tags: python, string

Ayuda, al momento de dar la respuesta sale con parentesis así: (1045.0, 550.0, 7095) y necesito que dé así:'1045,550,7095'

nó sé cómo arreglarlo

def calcular_iva_propina_total_factura (costo_factura:int)->str:

```
x= round(costo_factura*19/100)
y= round(costo_factura*10/100)
z= round(costo_factura+x+y)

return x,y,z
```

Answer (score 3):

`return x,y,z` es azúcar sintáctica, es equivalente a `return (x, y, z)`, es decir estas efectivamente retornando una tupla de tres enteros.

Para que retorne una cadena, debes crearla a partir de los tres enteros de forma explicita, lo mas simple es usar formateo de cadenas usando f-strings:

```
return f"{x},{y},{z}"
```

En algunas situaciones es conveniente usar [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) para estos casos, por ejemplo si tuvieras un numero indeterminado (mas bien determinado en tiempo de ejecución) de enteros.

```
return ",".join(map(str, (x, y, z)))
```

Pero en tu caso no merece la pena.